# Prove that $\sum_{n\leq k}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}$ is bounded.

Tags: number-theory

Let $k \geq1$. How can i show that $$\sum_{n \leq k} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = O(1).$$where $\mu(n)$ is the mobius function. 
I already tried the Euler Summation Formula but i can't show it. Is there any simple way to show this or does anyone have a link regarding this statement. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You might be interested in that question of mine in MO some years ago: https://mathoverflow.net/q/47469/7710

Comment: Turns out it's a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1595404) (my answer too; should have noted it before).

Answer (score 6):

Apply the ["second" Möbius inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations) to the constant function $1$: $$1=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\mu(n)\Big\lfloor\frac{k}{n}\Big\rfloor=k\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{k}\mu(n)\Big\{\frac{k}{n}\Big\}.$$
Now rearrange and note that the last sum is at most $k-1$ in absolute value.

Comment: (+1) Very neat!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way is to exploit the fact that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ for any $s\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\text{Re}(s)>1$.
The Riemann $\zeta$ function is a meromorphic function with a simple pole with residue $1$ at $s=1$ (for instance, this can be deduced from the integral representation
$$ \zeta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s+1)(1-2^{1-s})}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^s e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\,dx $$
providing an analytic continuation over $\text{Re}(s)>-1$) hence $$\lim_{s\to 1^+}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$ equals $0$ and the partial sums of $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}$ are bounded (since this is a convergent series).
We lose the information *bounded by what?*, of course.